# Button scale animation makes the background clip

Tags: android, button, objectanimator

I am scaling button when it is pressed down. But when i scale it, the background gets clipped. These are the photos

[image: This is normal button without click]

[image: This is when the button is clicked]

This is the button xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/record_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_transparent_button"/>
```

I had to use fixed width and height otherwise the background would come as oval and not circle.

This is rounded_transparent_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

and here is rounded_transparent_button_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
<solid android:color="#f00"/>
</shape>
```

and this is the animation code:

```
    captureButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        void scale(float scaleValue){
            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(captureButton, "scaleX", scaleValue);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(captureButton, "scaleY", scaleValue);
            scaleX.setDuration(100);
            scaleY.setDuration(100);
            AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
            scaleDown.play(scaleX).with(scaleY);
            scaleDown.start();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_transparent_button_pressed);
                        scale(1.5f);

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_transparent_button);
                    scale(1f);

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```